# PHP Image Link to Open PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

Evening All

I am currently writing some PHP it loops through an array and returns the results in a table.

One of the columns I would like to be titled "Drawing" this column will contain a PDF icon if a PDF file exists in a server location, if no file exists with a relevant name then it will be blank.

So far so good I have the above working!!

However when I click on the PDF icon nothing happens....

If I do a right click save target as I can save the PDF but this is not the behavior I would like to happen, I would like the PDF to open up in the browser and preview.

I am quite new to PHP programming so feel free to let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way!

Here is my PHP as of current:

```
<?php
// RETURN RESULTS
$results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $searchquery, $params );

if( $results === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
// BUILD FILE LOCATION NAME
    $filename = "\\\\domainname\\dfsr\\sharename\\foldername\\foldername\\foldername\\" . TRIM(strtolower($row['product'])) . ".pdf";

// CHECK IF FILE EXISTS OR NOT AND CREATE PDF ICON VARIABLE
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $pdf_drawing = "<a href=".$filename."> <img src=" . '"images/pdf_icon.png"' . " /> </a>";
    } else {
        $pdf_drawing = "";
    };
      echo "<tr>
//CREATE TABLE DATA PER ROW
                <td>".$row['warehouse']."</td>
                <td>".$row['product']."</td>
                <td>".$row['analysis_b']."</td>
                <td>".$row['long_description']."</td>
                <td>".$row['drawing_number']."</td>
                <td> " . $pdf_drawing . "</td>
            </tr>";
}
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Bepster

Comment: My browsers preview PDF files fine. It is only this page I am writing that is effected

Comment: If I remove the ". $pdf_drawing ." from the <td> to ". $filename ." it presents me with the correct file location. If I copy and paste this file location into my web browser it successfully loads the PDF

Comment: <a href=\\servername\dfsr\foldername\foldername\foldername\foldername\productname.pdf> <img src="images/pdf_icon.png" /> </a>
When I copy and paste the href link into my web browser manually it previews fine.

Comment: Still no luck. as I mentioned before if I right click "Save Target As" I can save the PDF so it must be something to do with how the page is trying to present the .PDF? I have PDF set up in IIS Mime types as far as I can see?!

Comment: I have seen this code on a few other pages but everywhere I seem to add it just causes the page to instantly try and open the first PDF document in the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Button does nothing, however when I hang over the button it gives me correct address for the file (e.g. how the image was behaving as well)

Comment: See below for answer mate!

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer automatically blocks all UNC paths unless the site is added into the intranet list

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning a target attribute?

for instance:

```
<a href=".$filename"target="_self"><img src="../../img.png"></a>
```

Comment: Hi mate, the issue is related to how browsers treat UNC paths.

All browsers block href links to UNC paths by default. in IE you can add the site to the intranet list to overcome this. Not 100% sure how you get around this issue in Firefox or Chrome, we only deploy IE in our company so not too much of a worry for me.